# Wordplay in an unknown domain

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> I took the name of a `XYZ`.
>   It starts with a `XYZ`.
>   I picked even letters only.
>   The result contains only letters which are in `XYZ`
>   and is the name of a `XYZ`.

What is `XYZ`? What did I start with?

`XYZ` is one word, but not necessarily three letters long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is that XYZ is:

> **"capital"**

You started with the name of a XYZ.

> **NAYPYIDAW**, the capital city of Myanmar

It starts with a XYZ.

> It starts with a capital letter, as proper nouns do in English.

I picked even letters only.

> Taking the 2nd, 4th, 6th, and 8th letters gives APIA.

The result contains only letters which are in XYZ

> The letters of APIA are all in the word "capital".

and is the name of a XYZ.

> **APIA** is the capital city of Samoa.

Comment: This is the intended answer. Nice work.

Comment: @jafe That's a really nifty find. How did you come across this?

Comment: I was just looking for an XYZ which contains all the letters in the answer. The fact that it was every second letter, and in the same order, was just lucky :)

Answer (score 4):

It’s kind of a stretch, but until I find a better answer, here goes my guess:

XYZ is

> Chemical

I took the name of a XYZ

> I choose Tin, a chemical in the periodic table

It starts with a XYZ

> Ti = Titanium

I picked even letter only

> Only one letter in my case, so “i”

The result matches \b[XYZ]+\b

> A regular expression that searches for whole words that is composed only by any amount of the characters in “chemical”. So in this case, “i” is composed by a character in “chemical” so the result matches.

And is the name of a XYZ

> “i” is also the name of a chemical, Iodine

Comment: Pretty good! The only part that's a bit of a stretch is the last step.